# Getting wrong value while filtering the missing value from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I want filter the missing number from an sequential array using javascript but I am getting the wrong value. I am explaining my code below.

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10];

arr1 = arr1.filter((item,pos) => {
  if(pos < arr1.length && arr1[pos+1] !== undefined) {
    if(item !== arr1[pos+1]-1){
      //console.log(item,arr1[pos+1]-1);
      return arr1[pos+1]-1;
    }
  }

})

console.log(arr1);
```

Here `9` is missing from my array but I am getting the output `[8]` as output.

Answer (score 2):

You need a different approach, because your filtering returns only a value which is **in** the array, not missing. As well as you not getting holes of more than one value.

This solution iterates the array and takes a variable for the expected value and if this value is smaller than the array value, it iterates until the given value from the array.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10],
    missing = [],
    value = array[0],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    while (value < array[i]) missing.push(value++);
    ++value;
}

console.log(missing);
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work for something like `[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10]`

Comment: that's ok ;). Your current method will still not work for unsorted arrays (like `[6, 14, 9, 8]`)

Comment: @KooiInc, come on. op has presented an ordered array. if not a sorting would help.

Comment: Ok, ok, maybe I read too much of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer today

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below. Here iterating over all items and check if the difference between current item and previous of current item is 1 or not if not then return (current item -1).

```js
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10];

for(var i = 1; i < arr1.length; i++) {
   if(arr1[i] - arr1[i-1] != 1) {
    console.log(arr1[i]-1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` method returns only [*existing elements which are evaluated to true in callback function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> filter() calls a provided callback function once for each element in
>   an array, and constructs a new array of **all the values for which
>   callback returns a value that coerces to true**.

So `filter` method cannot return incremented values from existing array.

You can use `reduce` method for finding gaps:

```js
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10];

arr1 = arr1.reduce((a, c, i) => {
  if ((c + 1) < arr1[i + 1])
    a.push(c + 1);
  return a;
}, [])

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As already said, you can't use `filter` as its purpose is to filter the values of the given array.

You could try using `reduce` in order to find multiple gaps:

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12];

arr1 = arr1.reduce((carry, item, index) => {
    item++;
    
    while (index !== arr1.length - 1 && item < arr1[index + 1]) {
        carry.push(item++);
    }
    
    return carry;
}, []);

console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: @KooiInc of course not, but the op already mentioned he has it ordered. If it's not ordered then a natural sort could be done before reducing